# custom regex for baserev for jfrog layout

Tags: artifactory

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts#RepositoryLayouts-PathPatternTokens

baserev seems to be required, but doesn't support regex? Is there a way I can use a custom token for the baserev instead?